# Stop rule execution - Drools

Tags: drools

How can I stop rule execution in Drools when find any rule. Rules are like this:

```
rule "Restore zxGponOltSDi IVR"
when
    $log: LogDTO (
        nameEvent in (
            "zxGponOltSDiRestore"
        )
    )
then
    insert ( 
        new RestoreEventAlarmDTO(
            $log.getNameEvent(), 
            new String[] {"zxGponOltSDi"},
            $log.getIp(), 
            new Date(),
            $log.getInterFace()
         )
    );
    //Add something for stopping execution 
 end
```

In drl file, there are 34 rules and the execution is taking too long. I´ll need that execution finalizes when find any rule.

```
package com.claro.cpymes.rule;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.drools.KnowledgeBase;
import org.drools.KnowledgeBaseFactory;
import org.drools.builder.*;
import org.drools.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession;

import com.claro.cpymes.dto.*;
import com.claro.cpymes.util.Constant;

public class RestoreEvent {

   private static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(RestoreEvent.class.getName());

   KnowledgeBase kbase;

   StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession;

   public void initialize() throws Exception {
      kbase = RestoreEvent.readKnowledgeBase(Constant.PATH_DRL_FILE_RESTORE);
      ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
   }

   public RestoreEventAlarmDTO restoreEvent(LogDTO log) {
      ksession.insert(log);
      ksession.fireAllRules();
      Collection<Object> listEventRestore = ksession.getObjects();
      RestoreEventAlarmDTO restoreEventAlarm = null;
      for (Object obj : listEventRestore) {
         if (obj instanceof RestoreEventAlarmDTO) {
            restoreEventAlarm = ((RestoreEventAlarmDTO) obj);
            ksession.retract(ksession.getFactHandle(obj));
            break;
         }
      }
      return restoreEventAlarm;
   }

   private static KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase(String drlFile) throws Exception {
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(drlFile);

      KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
      kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource(fis), ResourceType.DRL);
      KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = kbuilder.getErrors();
      if (errors.size() > 0) {
         for (KnowledgeBuilderError error : errors) {
            LOGGER.info(error);
         }
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse knowledge.");
      }
      KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
      kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
      return kbase;    
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
ksession.fireAllRules( 1 );
```

returns after the first rule firing.

Comment: If I have 2 rule table in excel, it is not working,

Comment: I suggest that you write a new question, providing sufficient detail so that your problem can be reproduced.